# I’ve been traveling quite a bit since we saw each other last Christmas

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions

1. I’**ve been traveling** *quite a bit* since we saw each other last Christmas.
2. I’**ve travelled** quite a bit since we saw each other last Christmas.
3. He’**s been spending** *a lot of time* at the gym.
4. He’**s spent** a lot of time at the gym.

Q) What is the difference between (1) and (2), (3) and (4)? If they're still travelling, what does the phrase "quite a bit" mean in sentence (1)? In sentence (3), has he been spending at the gym *a lot of time* **everyday**?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any great difference in meaning; the continuous tense may give more of a suggestion that the travels, or the visits to the gym, are continuing.

*Quite a bit* is just another way of saying *quite a lot.*  There is no indication as to *how* frequent the visits to the gym were.

Comment: I think I couldn't make myself understood. Consider these, please: "I have been reading **a lot of** books since the past week", "I have been drinking **a lot of** coffee since morning". Do they work the same way as sentence (1) or sentence (3) in the OP?

Comment: They work the same way as (1) _and_ (3), which both use the continuous tense (except that it would be better to say _during the past week_).

Comment: Just one last question: would these work: 1) "she's been drinking a lot of coffee *today*" 2) "she has been drinking at least a liter of coffee today"

Comment: (2) doesn't work.  The continuous implies a habitual or repeated action, but if a total quantity in a single period of time is mentioned, you have to say "She has drunk at least a litre today".